# How to send a list of image using multipart and retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I have to upload an array of images, and what i have done so far is this:

Request

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/user/api/v1/guest/readReceipts")
    suspend fun sendReceipt(
        @Body filesList: MutableList<MultipartBody.Part>
    ): Call<MutableList<OcrResponse>>
```

Repository

```
val requestFile = image.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())
            val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "file.jpg", requestFile)
            ocrRequests.sendReceipt(mutableListOf(body))
```

but this doesn't work. I also tried to change @Body to @Part, but doesn't work.

I now that this work

```
@Multipart
    @POST("profilo/avatar")
    fun setProfileImage(
        @Part file: MultipartBody.Part,
    ): Call<ProfileImageResponse>
```

because i have use it in an other project, but i don't manage to edit it to work with list of multipart

Comment: "but this doesn't work" -- what does "doesn't work" mean? What are your specific symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

Photo list arg should be marked by `@Part` annotation

```
@Multipart
@POST("/user/api/v1/guest/readReceipts")
suspend fun sendReceipt(
    @Part filesList: MutableList<MultipartBody.Part>
): Call<MutableList<OcrResponse>>
```

In array form-data case there should be square brackets `[]` as suffix for `MultipartBody.Part` field name

```
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file[]", "file.jpg", requestFile)
```